# Using BASH to annotate Intervals

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a very large text file with intervals of 500 (let's call it the main file.)  It looks something like this:

```
Line1 0 500
Line1 500 1000
Line1 1000 1500
```

I have a second file that has different annotations at various intervals (let's call it the secondary file.)

```
Annotation1 379 498
Annotation2 1002 1048
....
```

I want to create a third file that annotates the main file with the secondary file, to look something like this:

```
Line1 0 500 Annotation1
Line1 500 1000  NA
Line1 1000 1500 Annotation2
```

In the situation of overlaps, I would prefer that the first annotation that fits the interval is placed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far, and describe how it doesn't work.  The community is not a code writing service - we help you troubleshoot your own code.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Looks like @jww has downvoted all answers again to punish everyone for daring to reply to a question she doesn't like so I'm upvoting them all again to compensate. Sigh...

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{for(i in a)if(i-$2>=0 && $3-i>0)$0=$0 OFS a[i]}1' 2.txt 1.txt
```

Brief explanation,

1. `NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next`: in 2.txt, record $2 as the key and $1 as the value into array `a`
2. Scan array `a` to see if any key is between the range for each record in 1.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{
         min[$1]=$2
         max[$1]=$3 
         next
       }{
         for(i in min){
           if($2<=min[i] && $3>=max[i]){
             print $0,i 
             next
           }
         } 
         print $0,"NA"
       }' file2 file1
Line1 0 500 Annotation1
Line1 500 1000 NA
Line1 1000 1500 Annotation2
```

The first block statement stores the minimum, maximum and annotation values of the second file into the arrays `min` and `max`.

The second block statement loops through the array to find the annotation to print based on the max and min value of the current line. If the range doesn't match, the `NA` string is displayed.